# JDatechooser shows incorrect date

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jdatechooser

I'm working on java swing program.
to have date and store it's value in jtable i have been using Jdatechooser but it only works once when i run the file but after then it doesn't work and shows incorrect date.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");  
String date=sdf.format(jDateChooser2.getDate());
```

value in jtable

```
jDateChooser2.setDateFormatString((String) model.getValueAt(selectRow, 3));
```

code to store data in database :

```
String e_id;
        String type = type_exp.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String amount = amnt.getText();
 
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String date = sdf.format(jDateChooser2.getDate());
        String disc = disc_.getText();

        try {
            String sql = "insert into expance(type_expance,amount,exp_date,disc) values('" + type + "','" + amount + "','" + date + "','" + disc + "')";  //"++" use this pattern to pass variables
            int n = st.executeUpdate(sql);         //use this for insert/update/delte query and for searching ExecuteQuery
            if (n == 1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, n + " records saved successfully..");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "something went wrong");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex.getMessage());
        }
```

code to get values in jtable:

```
try {
            String sql = "select * from expance";
            rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
            DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
            model.setRowCount(0);
            while (rs.next()) {
                model.addRow(new Object[]{rs.getString("e_id"), rs.getString("type_expance"), rs.getString("amount"), rs.getString("exp_date"), rs.getString("disc")});
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: Did you try `setDate` instead of `setDateFormatString`?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code. If the code is relevant to your problem, post it in a snippet here.

Comment: @maloomeister ok.i'll keep that in mind, thanks for advise

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem yes i tried, but does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the format not the date.

```
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse((String) model.getValueAt(selectRow, 3));
//Sets format
jDateChooser2.setDateFormatString(pattern );
//Sets the date
jDateChooser2.setDate(date );
```